# Use Phonegap for SDK developement

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a native SDK which is integrated into a native app ("host app"). The app is calling my SDK method and this method will open a Webview (both for iOS and Android).

I looked into Phonegap as a solution, and saw that it gives me a platform for opening a Webview and communicating with the device. While this is ok, I cannot find a way to build this as the "SDK app" that I wanted, triggered by host native app, without writing the native code for that myself (duplicating my code for iOS and Android and dealing with native code).

Does Phonegap (or other platforms) have the ability to add a native logic (and not only webview) without the need to duplicate my code?

tnx!
Yaniv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is for developing apps. It is not really for third parties to create a library for others to use. While you can try to twist PhoneGap (and similar solutions) to serve that role, that will add extra baggage for anyone who would want to integrate with your library.

Hence, I suggest that you just create a library, sans PhoneGap.